# SpringMVC JAXB won't convert XML document if it has namespace

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jaxb

I have an XML document which I am try to convert into an Object. It looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
    <Items>
        <Request>
            <IsValid>false</IsValid>
            <ItemSearchRequest>
                <Keywords>php</Keywords>
                <ResponseGroup>Offers</ResponseGroup>
            </ItemSearchRequest>
        </Request>
    </Items>
    <OperationRequest>
        <HTTPHeaders>
            <Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36" />
        </HTTPHeaders>
        <RequestId>1e3171b9-c476-4833-90ff-bc65ebca09e7</RequestId>
    </OperationRequest>
</ItemSearchResponse>
```

But whenever I include this part in the XML file `xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"` It does not work. I simply read an XML file feed it to JAXB and try to output it again to see if I get the same structure in the browser. This is my code.

```
@RequestMapping("/samplexml")
public SampleXML CreateXMLFile () throws EncoderException {
     try {

            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Caciocode\\eclipse-workspace\\earplugs\\src\\main\\resources\\public\\samplexml.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SampleXML.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            SampleXML sample = (SampleXML) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(sample);
            return sample;

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }
}
```

After reading around I think I need to create a NamespacePrefixMapper. If that's the case please show me how to. The namespace will always be there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SampleXML` class will need to have the namespace specified (as will all the contained object classes), I generally do this using package info so it will cover the whole package.